# AdMob and ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, admob, actionbarsherlock

I have an android app that uses ActionbarSherlock and I want to put an ad at the bottom of a ListView screen.

I have followed the information available here https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals and it doesn't compile saying "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdView"

So my question is:
What do I have to do to get the ad to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have what ADT version? 17?
If so try to rename the `lib` folder to `libs`

The ADT 17 of Android Tools requires the /lib folder to be /libs.

This problem is due to the fact:

> that libraries are not managed the same way with the new ADT build.
> Instead of having 2 different managements of libraries (one for
> Android Library Projects, one for the standard jars), now both are
> merged into the Android Dependencies item.

See more information in  [this link](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17)

Comment: If moving the library into the proper spot isn't desirable, you can also go to properties->java build path->order and export. Click the libraries that need to be exported, and they are manually included.